# Near-future sci-fi/fantasy story for young adults

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, soft-sci-fi

I'm looking for a book I read a few years ago, around 2010-2014. It was about a boy who lived in a world where kids and teenagers can play recreational games like golf, tennis, etc. if they work at a place where they sort out what happens to lost things. For example, he's introduced to this with a lost puppy. He can decide to return it immediately, after a short amount of time, or never. Instinctively, he chooses immediately, but reads the document that comes with it, saying the dog's owner, a boy around his age, is mean to his dog. He then chooses the second option, to help the boy learn his worth. That's about as much as I can remember, but I do remember that there's wind turbines that spin on their own, apparently generating their own power to keep them spinning.

Thanks in advance!

(It makes me think about all of the lost ballpoint pens in the world)

Comment: Interesting. Check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: I've checked that, but it didn't seem to bring up anything else, sorry. It was by a not very well known author, I think.